# Applet content works with Eclipse but not in my browser

Tags: java, html, eclipse, japplet

Hello I am trying to make an applet from my Java application.

My application starts with a Testpan.java class which extends a JPanel.
I made a AppletLauncher.java class to use it in an applet. I compiled this AppletLauncher with Eclipse as either an applet, either an application. In both cases my program works. However when I try to load it in my web browser using a html file, the contained Testpan JPanel doesn't show at all. I first suspected it had to do with the paint() metho used in my applet class, however it works with Eclipse. I don't understand why it does not work inside my web browser (Firefox). I think I used JApplet's methods correctly, didn't I?

Here is my AppletLauncher.java code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class AppletLauncher extends JApplet {

    public static Dimension dimWindow = new Dimension(500,300) ;

    protected Testpan tp;

    public AppletLauncher() {

    }

    // Common initialization for either JApplet or JFrame
    private void initContainer(Container container) {
        System.out.println("initCOntainer");
        //container.setLocation(10, 10);
        container.setPreferredSize(dimWindow);

    tp = new Testpan();
    tp.setVisible(true);
    container.add(tp);
    //container.add(new Testpan(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    //setBackground(Color.red);

    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initializing...");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                initContainer(AppletLauncher.this);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Destroying applet...");
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("paint AppletLauncher");
        g.drawString("Hello wor\nld!", 100, 50);
        setBackground(Color.red);
        tp.paint(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { 
                System.out.println("inside main method");
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("myApplet!");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setPreferredSize(dimWindow) ;
                frame.setResizable(false);

                AppletLauncher applet = new AppletLauncher();
                applet.initContainer(frame);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true) ;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is my Testpan code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Testpan extends JPanel {


    public Testpan() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("inside testpan paintComponent");
        String str = "BioSnake";
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 50));
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int x = (g.getClipBounds().width - fm.stringWidth(str)) / 2;
        int y = (g.getClipBounds().height / 2) + fm.getMaxDescent();
        g.drawString(str, x, y);

    }

}
```

Here you find my html code:

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>My first applet!</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>


 <APPLET code="AppletLauncher.class" width="500" height ="400">
You should see the applet here..
 </APPLET>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/applet) maybe `applet` is disabled  in FF

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.